# Add value to specific key and datetime

Tags: java, android, datetime, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app where are few users. Each user can save item to firebase. But when a user save an item that item save under a **date time** child, and under **user** 
name.

That's how my items are saved and users available

[image]

And instead of numbers (0,1,2) I want to appear date time and user name. Hope the question is ok i couldn't find any tutorial. 
Here is my code :

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("jsonData").child("listaVanzatoareProduse");
            databaseReference.setValue(Util.getInstance().getVanzatorProduse());

            Util.getInstance().getVanzatorProduse().clear();
```

Comment: What returns this line of code: `Util.getInstance().getVanzatorProduse()`?

Comment: It returns jsonData and listaVanzatoareProduse

Comment: If i understand correctly, it returns a `List`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, with products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.child()` method creates a new node if it doesn't exists. so you can simply do:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("jsonData").child("listaVanzatoareProduse").child(dateTime).child(userName);
databaseReference.setValue(Util.getInstance().getVanzatorProduse());
```

Comment: Yeah, but thats the problem I don't know how can I make my dateTime with numbers and for userName I want for each user when is selecting products to appear his name and products selected

Comment: as datetime I would use the timestamp (`System.currentTimeMillis()`), userName you get it from firebase auth.